# Get current user location with dialogflow-fulfillment library

Tags: geolocation, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am creating a Dialogflow chatbot using `dialogflow-fulfillment` Nodejs Client library and will integrate it with a smartphone application. I want to fetch the user location but on the Internet, I could only find the helper functions for `actions-on-google` which I believe only works for Google Assistant. What I want to do is if a user says *Swimming places near me*, it automatically fetches its location.

Comment: Are you trying to write this so it works with integrations *other than* the Google Assistant? Or are you trying to do this for the Google Assistant but using the `dialogflow-fulfillment` library?

Comment: @Prisoner for integration (mobile app). This is not for Google Assistant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Chatbot is integrated in a mobile app or web app, fetch location data on app level and send it in meta-data/custom payload when making query request to dialogflow

Dialogflow fulfilment is a helper library which is a wrapper on https api, whatever you can with dialogflow rest apis you can do the same with dialoglfow fulfilment library